# Using rpy2, how to call a fuction with a "." in the variable name?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I would like to use rpy2 to call the regsubsets function from the R leaps package. Sine there seems to be no python equivalent (at least non-that I have found).

```
import pandas
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages

pandas2ri.activate()
leaps = rpackages.importr("leaps")


x = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,10))
y = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10))

leaps.regsubsets(x=x, y=y, nbest=10, nvmax=3, really.big=T)
```

Calling that function does require the argument **really.big=T**. That of course does not work, because in python the . has a direct function as opposed to R. (i get a "SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression"). Can anyone tell me how to call it from rpy2?

I have tried to do it with kwargs like `leaps.regsubsets({"x":x ... "really.big":T})` but that also does not work and I also do not know what "T" is in R.

OK, I found out that the ["." gets transleted to "_"](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/robjects_functions.html). but sadly it still does not work, somehow the argument does not get passed on.

```
leaps.regsubsets(x=X, y=Y, nbest=10, nvmax=3, really_big=True)
```

still gives me the error:
RRuntimeError:

```
Error in leaps.exhaustive(a, really.big = really.big) : 
  Exhaustive search will be S L O W, must specify really.big=T
```

Comment: You have to define *T* if you want to use it as an identifier. Don't know anything about *R* (or *rpy*), but if you go with the *kwargs* approach, try: `... "really.big": "T"`, or maybe `leaps.T` ?.

Comment: it turns out that T in R is just True -- so that riddle is solved, still how can I call the function with an agrument like "really.big" from python?

Comment: Yes, https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/leaps/versions/3.0/topics/regsubsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation link in the comments in for rpy2-2.2.x that is quite old. Documentation for the current release is at:

https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.0.x/html/robjects_functions.html

Otherwise the documentation is rather clear about the near-impossibility of extracting parameters that can be accepted in the R ellipsis (`...`) (which is what @CristiFati is pointing out in the comments).

You can used syntactically-invalid parameter names with `**`. For example here:

```
leaps.regsubsets(x=x, y=y,
                 nbest=10, nvmax=3,
                 **{'really.big': true})
```